# Javascript Div's Width According to Screen Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.com/) for my website, I want change my slider's width according to visitor's screen width. I'm using width: 650px for 1366px width, so default rate is ~0.48

I have a JS like this:

```
function loadwidth() { document.getElementById('main-slider').style.width = "\'" + ((screen.width / 100) * 0.48) + "px\'";
```

and body in html has:

```
onlad="loadwidth()"
```

but it don't change width of my div.
How can I fix it?

Comment: And why do you use `"\'"` ???

Comment: because I need '500px' format, not 500px. So "\'" + 500 + "px\'" = '500px'

Comment: But setting style.width to "`'500px'`" instead of "`500px`" doesn't make sense! It makes the value illegal and the browser therefore ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
function loadwidth() { 
    var w = (screen.width / 100) * 0.48;
    document.getElementById('main-slider').setAttribute("style","width:"+w+"px");
}
```

and change:

```
onload="loadwidth()"
```

Comment: You should also check the width calculation, i think the formula is wrong

Comment: You were right! Calculation must be like this: (screen.width / 100) * 48. But now, I need change all fonts' size via ratio again.